# how to install kubernetes manually?

Tags: kubernetes

While getting familiar with kubernetes I do see tons of tools that should helps me to install kubernetes anywhere, but I don't understand exactly what it does inside, and as a result don't understand how to trouble shoot issues.

Can someone provide me a link with tutorial how to install kubernetes without any tools.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two good guides on setting up Kubernetes manually:

- Kelsey Hightower's [Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)
- Kubernetes guide on [getting started from scratch](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/)

Kelsey's guide assumes you are using GCP or AWS as the infrstructure, while the Kubernetes guide is a bit more agnostic.

I wouldn't recommend running either of these in production unless you really know what you're doing. However, they are great for learning what is going on under the hood. Even if you just read the guides and don't use them to setup any infrastructure you should gain a better understanding of the pieces that make up a Kubernetes cluster. You can then use one of the helpful setup tools to create your cluster, but now you will understand what it is actually doing and can debug when things go wrong.

Comment: The first link is just something I was looking for

Comment: @pixel-elephant what would you recommend to install kubernetes on bare metal on-premises ?

Answer (score 14):

For simplicity, you can view k8s as three components

- etcd
- k8s master, which includes kube-apiserver, controller, scheduler
- node, which contains kubelet

You can install etcd and k8s master **together in one machine**. The procedures are

1. Install etcd. Download etcd package and run it, which is quite
   simple. Remember the port of etcd service, e.g. 2379,4001, or any you
   set.
2. Git clone the kubernetes project from github. Find the executable binary file, e.g. for k8s version 1.3, you can find kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler in **src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/bin/linux/amd64** folder
3. Then run kube-apiserver, specify the etcd ip and port (e.g. **--etcd_servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001**)
4. Run scheduler and controller, specifying the apiserver ip and port(e.g. **--master=127.0.0.1:8080**). There is no oreder between scheduler and controller
5. Master is running so far. Make sure these processes run without errors. If etcd exits, apiserver would exit. If apiserver exits, scheduler and controller would exit.
6. **On another machine**(virtual preferred, network connected), run kubelet. Kubelet could also be found in previous folder(src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/bin/linux/amd64), specify apiserver ip and port(e.g. --api-servers=http://10.10.10.19:8080). You may install docker or something else on node, which to prove that you could create a container.

Comment: @abovesun, not mandatory if just for master and nodes' connectivity.